# Concatenate fields in a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, return, concatenation

I created an API where i want to get the return of some fields all together, I tried to concatenate them but it isn't giving me the result in a string.

```
export async function getByContaBancariaEmpresarialDescricao() {
  const resource = await Resource.query()
    .select('descricao', 'agencia', 'digito_agencia', 'conta', 
'digito_conta', 'ibi.codigo as bancoCodigo', 'ibi.numero as 
bancoNumero', 'ibi.banco as bancoNome', 'ibi.IMAGEM_LOGO as 
bancoICONE',
    ('descricao as ContaBancariaEmpresarialDescricao'),
    (`descricao`, '+', `conta`, '+', `ibi.numero`)
  )

    .joinRelation('banco', { alias: 'ibi' });


  return resource;
}
```

And it's returning this:

```
{
        "descricao": "BANCO TRIBANCO",
        "agencia": "1111",
        "digitoAgencia": "1",
        "conta": "1111",
        "digitoConta": "1",
        "bancoCodigo": 11,
        "bancoNumero": "111",
        "bancoNome": "BANCO TRIANGULO S/A",
        "bancoICONE": null,
        "ContaBancariaEmpresarialDescricao": "BANCO TRIBANCO",
        "numero": "111"
},
```

Is there a way to get a return of 'descricao + conta + bancoNumero' all together in a single string?

Comment: Can you please share the expected output?

Comment: Or are you looking for something like this :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties

Comment: The expected result would be:
            "ContaBancariaEmpresarialDescricao": "BANCO TRIBANCO, 1111, 111".

Where ContaBancariaEmpresarialDescricao gives me the values of descricao + conta + bancoNumero.

Comment: @VicenteLimaLemes Use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51266799/edit) button please!!!

Comment: @VicenteLimaLemes, i see the result and the expectation same !

Comment: The ContaBancariaEmpresarialDescricao is returning only 'descricao', and not all three fields together.

Comment: I think the problem is here: 
     ('descricao as ContaBancariaEmpresarialDescricao'),
         (`descricao`, '+', `conta`, '+', `ibi.numero`)

But I don't know how to change it to return all the three fields I want as ContaBancariaEmpresarialDescricao.

Answer (score 0):

Before this `return resource;` statement do the following to have the expected results as mentioned in the comment:

```
var newValue = [resource['ContaBancariaEmpresarialDescricao'], resource['conta'],resource['bancoNumero']].join(','); 
resource['ContaBancariaEmpresarialDescricao'] =newValue;
return resource;
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a JSON , you can parse this to JavaScript Object and the concatenate the fields, like this:

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{"descricao": "BANCO TRIBANCO","agencia": "1111","digitoAgencia": "1","conta": "1111","digitoConta": "1","bancoCodigo": 11,"bancoNumero": "111","bancoNome": "BANCO TRIANGULO S/A", "bancoICONE": null,"ContaBancariaEmpresarialDescricao": "BANCO TRIBANCO","numero": "111"}');

var result = obj.descricao +' ' + ' '+obj.conta + ' ' +obj.bancoNumero;
```